# Json show prefect in Browser But Android get Html Response?

Tags: php, android, json, .htaccess

I Use json in my android application . Before i disable gzip in my server every thing worked prefect , But when i add `SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary` To htaccess file . my json response show as html document in android log .

This Screen Shot Show Log :

[image]

Comment: Try after setting content type in PHP end.

Comment: show your php code.

Comment: As you can see you get error 404 - you have something wrong in your request url - Add interceptor to print request and try it via some rest tool (f.e. postman)

Comment: It Worked On postman . I add postman screenshot